# Express.js OAuth: "invalid_request: The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application."

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm using `passport-asana` to pass a few credentials to an OAuth server (on asana.com).

I get to the scope grant page, and log into the service.

But during the callback step I see this in the browser window:

```
/*
invalid_request: The `redirect_uri` parameter does not match a valid url for the application.
*/
```

Here is how I'm passing OAuth credentials, and also the route handlers for the initial and callback OAuth steps:

```
const callbackURL: string = `${process.env.DOMAIN}/oauth/callback`;

const asanaStrategy = new AsanaStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.ASANA_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL,
}, (asanaAccessToken: any, asanaRefreshToken: any, asanaProfile: any, doneCallback: Function) => {
  findAndPassUserToSerializer(asanaProfile.id, doneCallback);
});

passport.use(asanaStrategy);


// router file, exporting passport object above
router.get(
  '/oauth',
  passportWithAsanaStrategy.authenticate('Asana'),
  (req: Request, res: Response) => { /* IGNORED */ },
);

router.get(
  '/oauth/callback',
  passportWithAsanaStrategy.authenticate('Asana', { failureRedirect: '/login' },
    (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/');
    }),
);
```

**Also tried**

Encoding the first line with `encodeURI`:

```
const callbackURL: string = encodeURI(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/oauth/callback`);
```

The error is the same.

Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to indicate there is a mismatch between the redirect URL passed vs what is registered within the application settings.

I would recommend navigating to Asana's Developer Console and comparing the redirect URLs registered to confirm they match the final value of `${process.env.DOMAIN}/oauth/callback`.

Documentation on the request parameters: https://developers.asana.com/docs/oauth#user-authorization-endpoint